# What's the meaning of this part of code in Linux source code?

Tags: linux

```
ENTRY(gdt_table)
 .quad 0x0000000000000000 /* NULL descriptor */

 .quad 0x0000000000000000 /* not used */

 .quad 0x00cf9a000000ffff /* 0x10 kernel 4GB code at 0x00000000 */

 .quad 0x00cf92000000ffff /* 0x18 kernel 4GB data at 0x00000000 */

 .quad 0x00cffa000000ffff /* 0x23 user 4GB code at 0x00000000 */

 .quad 0x00cff2000000ffff /* 0x2b user 4GB data at 0x00000000 */

 .quad 0x0000000000000000 /* not used */

 .quad 0x0000000000000000 /* not used */
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table

Comment: it's defining a array,right?

Comment: This isn't Linux code.  gdt is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/stackprotector.h#L106